# my range rover sport 2007 do not goes above 100km/h

Tags: bmw, rover, range

my range rover sport 2007 does not  go above  100km/h since I changed the air shocks to a manual shocks
please help me out,im in Africa and we don't have professional mechanics for such type of vehicles, I have spent a lot on this issue yet no positive results, it only stops at 90km with full acceleration

Comment: Have you checked the codes? Probably the control modules are limiting the speed due to a lack of signals from the suspension.

Comment: thanks I will ask my mechanic to do that straight away