# What could be the problem with my Range Rover going off when driving?

Tags: automatic-transmission, performance, breakdown

What could be the problem with my Range Rover going off when driving? I need to stop and restart it over again at times it doesn't pull after restarting , I need to wait for some few minutes before restarting it over again

Comment: Didn’t your mechanic help? See https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/63554/10976

Comment: What does "going off" mean?

Comment: How is this different from your last question @GlobexDocumentsCompany? Did you get the codes read? If not you won't get an answer.

Comment: While not a strict duplicate of the other question I can't help but think they are intrinsically linked and it would be more effective to keep them together

Comment: I also think that the issues are linked either due to what was done or due to what was not done when doing those modifications...